# Multiselect header filter is throwing Uncaught TypeError

Tags: tabulator

I'm attempting to configure a header filter where I'm able to select multiple options to filter on. I'm using v5.2.2 and it keeps throwing an Uncaught TypeError.

`Uncaught TypeError: this.initialValues.join is not a function List.js:73:50`

I've tried a few different configuration options such as using the valuesLoopup set to 'active' or a hard coded set of values. I just wanted to double check on here to see if I'm doing something wrong before I submit it as a bug.

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eg3uzc92/17/) of my functioning setup. If I uncomment the multiselect configuration on line 45, the error get's thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem thanks to someone pointing to another post on setting up header filters. Thanks! Looks like I forgot to specify the headerFilterFunc to be "in" which I'm guessing is required with the multiselect option.

Edit: Never mind. This didn't work.

Comment: Has that solved your problem because while trying, I did that but it didn't solve it ?@Ryon

Comment: You know what? I thought I did, but I must have still had the multiselect commented out when I answered, because I'm still having the problem.

Comment: Yeah...'multiselect' actually is a param of 'editorParams' and although Header filters are also dependent on the edit module, 'multiselect' in 'headerFilterParams` doesn't work. It would be better to design your own custom filter function I guess. @Ryon

Comment: Something must have changed in 5.2.2 then. I have a working table using 5.1.8 where I have a column config:
`title: "Org Job Title",
field: "title",
headerHozAlign: "center",
headerFilter: 'select',

headerFilterFunc: "in",

headerFilterParams: {values: true, sortValuesList:true, multiselect:true},
  headerFilterPlaceholder: "Select Org Job Title(s)...",`

I guess I assumed that the new list filter functioned the same as the old select type. @SM1312